# By using java how can I calculate word count which give me result same as MS-Office word count functionality

Tags: java, regex, apache-tika, aspose.words

I/P file : doc,docx with en-dash,em-dash

I have implemented functionality for word count by using Apache Tika (metadata property) & Aspose wordtojava(library ) but they not giving me accurate result of word count.

en-dash & em-dash word count differs from MS-Office 
ex.
2—3
4–5
result : 
MS-office gives word count 4 for above example
APache - Tika  & Aspose library  gives word count 2

How I can calculate correct word count same as given by MS-Office?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Need quick response.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Extract all the string from the doc into one String.
Split them using this regex "[\n\t\r\f \p{Pd}]", and count the length of the splitted string array.

```
    String allWords = "2—3 4–5";
    String[] split = allWords.split("[\n\t\r\f \\p{Pd}]");
    System.out.println(split.length);
```

It prints 4.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The 'BuiltInDocumentProperties.Words' property represents an estimate of the number of words in the Word document. Aspose.Words updates this property when you call 'Document.updateWordCount' method. Please see the following sample code:

```
Document doc = new Document(getMyDir() + "in.docx");

// Update the word, character and paragraph count of the document.
doc.updateWordCount();

// Display the updated document properties.
System.out.println("Characters: " + doc.getBuiltInDocumentProperties().getCharacters());
System.out.println("Words: " + doc.getBuiltInDocumentProperties().getWords());
System.out.println("Paragraphs: " + doc.getBuiltInDocumentProperties().getParagraphs());
```

Hope, this helps.

Also, please make sure that you're using [latest version of Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/72/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) i.e. 15.7.0.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Hi Awais,  I have applied the code for aspose which is as below & I'm using latest words for java 15.7.0

Comment: I suggest you please report the issue in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) with the source Word document and server codes you're using on your end. We will investigate the issue in detail on our end and provide you more information via your thread.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at 
https://github.com/maresja1/Word-Counter/blob/master/README.md
It uses Apache tika and can handle doc, docx, rtf, pdf, etc. I looked at the code and it is actually a character counter that removes duplicate white spaces. But it can easily be changed to a word counter.